# Qt Creator doesn't display QML folder

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have a Qt project in Qt Creator. I have a `qrc` file with the QMLs registered and everything works. However for some reason the "projects" view of Qt Creator doesn't show the QML folder (screenshot attached) like it does for any example project.

I'm just curious. Why does QML folder not show in my project but it shows up for the example projects?

[image: list of folders]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add them to your .pro file (if I'm not wrong it's enough to append them to `DISTFILES`).

Comment: Sorry, was not `SOURCES`, but `DISTFILES`. Fixed the response.

Comment: Yep - this is the conclusion I came up with - thanks.  One more question, is there a way to automatically do it, or must it be a manual thing?

Answer (score 1):

Figures that you have to add the files to the `DISTFILES` directive.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer. :-)